# Removing null values when concatenating columns in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to implement a function to concatenate columns based on inputs provided by the user.
I have implemented it using a SQLAlchemy update statement:

```
update_statement = table.update().values({
        new_column_name: assignable
    })
```

where `assignable` is:

```
assignable = column_1 + column_2
```

where `column_1` and `column_2` are instances of `sqlalchemy.sql.column`.

It works fine but if one of the rows in column is empty i.e. has a `None` value it returns `None` as the result of concatenation.

I understand that's logical but is there a way I can convert `None` to '' (empty string) using this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can maybe use the coaslesce function

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html

```
class sqlalchemy.sql.functions.coalesce(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can specify default values for null result :)

Try googling coalesce for more results about this feature

So your "convert None to '' (empty string)" can be done like this

```
coalesce(column1, '') + coalesce(column2, '')
```